# URL changing link

Tags: java, html, url, thymeleaf

On my HTML-page I have a link for saving recipe, example

addrecipe?id=607691&name=Soft-Bread-Salami-Rolls

It looks like the correct URL when I hold the mouse over the link,
but the browser(?) converts it to something like this

addrecipe?id=607691%26name%3DSoft-Bread-Salami-Rolls

I managed to put atleast id= in the html but I get error when trying to add name= also.

```
<a th:href="@{'/addrecipe'(id=${recipesinfo.link})}" th:text=Save></a>
```

Comment: What error do you get when you try and add `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#adding-parameters) and assuming `recipesinfo.link` contains your `607691` ID (and nothing else), I think you should be using

```html
<a th:href="@{/addrecipe(id=${recipesinfo.link},name='Soft-Bread-Salami-Rolls')}">Save</a>
```

If the `name` value comes from a variable (eg `recipesinfo.name`), then you would use `name=${recipesinfo.name}` instead of the string literal.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being a bit unclear, my problem was solved with adding "," in html :)